# SVG Image float: left not working in HTML and CSS code

Tags: python, html, css, svg

Trying to create side by side with SVG image and Table. I have Python Generated SVG and Table output. Could not align SVG as left side and right as table using HTML and css.

HTML :

```
<div class="double_column_row_70_30">
    <div class="row_left_column_70_30">
        <h3>Index Performance</h3>
        <div class="svg-container">
            {{index_performance}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_right_column_70_30">
        <h3>Annual Index Return</h3>
        {{annual_index_returns}}
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.double_column_row_70_30 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.row_left_column_70_30 {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

.row_right_column_70_30 {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}

.row_left_column_70_30 img{
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}


.svg-container {
    flex: 1;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.svg-container svg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Output :

[image]

Expected Output :

[image]

Comment: use `row_left_column_70_30 ` not `row_right_column_70_30`

Comment: as everything will float against each other... so only do `float:left` also `double_column_row_70_30` should be `clear:both;`

Comment: and not `float:left`